# is it possible to create object for interface without implementing this by any of the classes in java?

Tags: java, interface

Itest is an Interface. here i mentioned like new Itest(). Then is it means that i can create object for interface?

```
public interface Itest {


}
static final Itest s = new Itest(){
};
```

It is just like, we could create object for interface without any class implement the interface.

Comment: If you are testing you need mocking. Look for a mocking library as jMock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is [anonymous classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm).

They are most commonly used something like this:

```
interface Something { void execute(); }

// In some code...
setSomething(new Something() {
   public void execute() { 
       // Your code here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{      
    interface ISampleInterface
    {
        void SampleMethod();
    }

    class ImplementationClass : ISampleInterface
    {
        // Explicit interface member implementation: 
       public void SampleMethod()
        {
            // Method implementation.
            Console.Write("Interface implements");  
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Declare an interface instance.
            ISampleInterface obj = new ImplementationClass();

            // Call the member.
            obj.SampleMethod();
            ImplementationClass a = new ImplementationClass();
            a.SampleMethod();
            ISampleInterface b = (ISampleInterface)a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like C# code. This question is about Java.